# MouseUp event is not fired when ellipse is on boundaries of canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, mouseevent

I'm building an app that displays a moveable joystick. The joystick can be moved freely within the (outer) canvas boundaries (i.e., its `Width` and `Height`), using `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` events.

As you can see in the C# code for `MouseUp`, the joystick should return to the center.

However, sometimes, when the joystick is positioned just on the boundary of the canvas (represented by the perimeter of the outer `Ellipse`, it doesn't return to the center. In fact, `MouseUp` just doesn't fire.

Why does `MouseUp` doesn't fire?

P.S - I reduced my XAML code to simple shapes (outer ellipse, representing the joystick base, and inner ellipse, represeting the joystick itself).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
    <Grid>
        <Canvas  x:Name="Base" Margin="0" Width="340" Height="340">
            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="340" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340">
               <Ellipse.Fill>
                   <RadialGradientBrush>
                       <GradientStop Color="#FF2C2A2A" Offset="1" />
                       <GradientStop Color="#FF3A3737" />
                   </RadialGradientBrush>
               </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <Canvas  x:Name="Knob" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="0" Height="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="125" Canvas.Top="125" MouseDown="Knob_MouseDown" MouseMove="Knob_MouseMove" MouseUp="Knob_MouseUp">
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Top="1">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <RadialGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF8A8A8A" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF979797" Offset="1" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="knobPosition" />
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Canvas.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="CenterKnob" Name="centerKnob" Completed="centerKnob_Completed">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="knobPosition"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="knobPosition" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Canvas.Resources>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void centerKnob_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private Point point = new Point();
        private void Knob_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            {
                point = e.GetPosition(this);
            }
        }

        private void Knob_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                double x = e.GetPosition(this).X - point.X;
                double y = e.GetPosition(this).Y - point.Y;

                if (Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y) < Base.Width / 2)
                {
                    knobPosition.X = x;
                    knobPosition.Y = y;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Knob_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            knobPosition.X = 0;
            knobPosition.Y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `MouseUp` don't get fired because it's executed only when the user release the joystick. If it exit the boundaries of the canvas before that then `MouseLeave` get fired. So you have to reset the `knobPosition` also in that scenario..

```xml
<!-- [...] -->
<Canvas  x:Name="Knob" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="0" Height="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="125" Canvas.Top="125" MouseDown="Knob_MouseDown" MouseMove="Knob_MouseMove" MouseUp="Knob_MouseUp" MouseLeave="Knob_MouseLeave">
<!-- [...] -->
```

and

```cs
private void Knob_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    knobPosition.X = 0;
    knobPosition.Y = 0;
}
```

I hope I was helpful.